# Use of "Single" in Dynamic Linq

Tags: linq

I am trying to convert a Linq query that I have working in Linq to be able to work in dynamic linq (using System.Linq.Dynamic) because I want a user to be able to form their own queries and this query string would be added onto other query strings at runtime.

I have a query:

```
db.incidents.Where(a => a.incidentLocations.Single().location.street.Contains(location);
```

and I have tried to convert it to the following dynamic linq string:

```
query = 
string.Concat("incidentLocations.Single().location.street.Contains(\"", location, "\")");

db.incidents.Where(query);
```

Where location is a string that includes search text.

I have managed to convert all my other queries to dynamic linq but this one i am struggling with the exception error:

"No applicable aggregate method 'Single' exists"

I understand that dynamic linq does not support all extension methods, could someone possibly tell me how I could get round this problem.

Comment: I have never used Dynamic Linq, but have you tried `SingleOrDefault()` ? It does more or less the same thing. Only it returns `null` when the record isn't found instead of throwing an error.

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with Dynamic Linq, but is it to SQL or Objects?

Comment: Perhaps single should be First()?

Comment: Since you can combine multiple linq queries into one giant expression, why are you converting your hard coded parts to be dynamic? Keep them as they were, and then just add in the extra queries for dynamic as additional filters or subselects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the source of Linq.Dynamic, copy paste the Where method, change the signature and the string with the function name inside the method and you're good to go. I did it to add Single First etc, I can't copy it here because I'm not on my dev machine but I'll do it later if necessary ;)

EDIT: here's the Single method if you decide to use it:

```
public static object Single(this IQueryable source)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        return source.Provider.Execute(
            Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable), "Single",
                new Type[] { source.ElementType },
                source.Expression));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yer I looked at doing this but I thought it more trouble than its worth to start modfiying the source. In the end I altered the dbml mapping relationships (which where quite complex) to avoid the need to use single() like Manatherin
said.

Comment: Although I cannot verify that your answer works now because I have solved the problem differently and the project has deployed! thanks for going to the trouble of trying to solve my problem. (Sorry I do not have enough reputation to upvote you.)

Comment: If you add this method, you'll also need to add Single to the IEnumerableSignatures interface (in the same file).

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to digg up a very old thread, but I thought I could add somevaluable information!

I had to do this for First()/FirstOrDefault() with Linq to Entities instead of your Linq to SQL and I can confirm @Guillaume86 's solution sure works!

Here's how I modified MicrosoftDynamic.sql:
I added this inside the static DynamicQueryable class:

```
    public static object FirstOrDefault(this IQueryable source)
        {
            if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
            return source.Provider.Execute(
                Expression.Call(
                    typeof(Queryable), "FirstOrDefault ",
                    new Type[] { source.ElementType },
                    source.Expression));
        }
```

I also modified interface IEnumerableSignatures as

```
            void FirstOrDefault();
```

(I used FirstOrDefault because First() isn't supported when it's not the last call in linq to entities)

You can repeat this for any supported function :)

Comment: I asked this question a long time ago, but I now set it as the answer.