# Ordering by ICollection property using its name as string with Dynamic Linq Library

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, dynamic-linq

I've searched pretty much every question, blog or documentation I could find to help me get to this question's answer. A few actually helped me get closer to it, but I still haven't solved it yet, since most were either outdated or not really on point with what I needed. Don't bother telling me about Expressions, since if I were to take the longer route, I wouldn't be using this library.

My project goal is to supply filtering and ordering by using generic methods, by using only the tables/columns name strings and the values used for filtering. Long story short, I have two tables, with a relation of 1 to n, connected basically like this and I want to order by the customer's name:

```
public partial class Transactions{
    public ICollection<Customer> customer { get; set; };
}

public partial class Customer{
    public string name { get; set; };
}
```

So far I have pretty much I should need to achieve what I want, except figuring out how to structure the OrderBy string properly, in a way I'd use a single ICollection result.

What I have so far is pretty much like this (sorry for being too verbose on my documentation):

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace com.betha.common
{
    public class Filter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Dictionary of codenames and column names populated by a different, specific class (properties.Add("customer", "tb_customer.name"))
        /// </summary>
        public Dictionary<string, string> properties;

        public Filter(Dictionary<string, string> properties)
        {
            this.properties = properties;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generic method designed to filter and order using just lists of column names and values
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the first IQueryable</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="T2">Type of the second IQueryable</typeparam>
        /// <param name="query">IQueryable containing the results from the parent table (context.table1).AsQueryable();</param>
        /// <param name="query2">IQueryable containing a single result from a descendant table (context.table2.Select(t2 => t2.field).FirstOrDefault()).AsQueryable();</param>
        /// <param name="prop">Property codename that if used, matches a properties codename Key</param>
        /// <param name="descend">Condition for ascending or descending results</param>
        /// <returns>Ordered and/or filtered IQueryable</returns>
        public IQueryable<T> FilterandOrder<T, T2>(IQueryable<T> query, IQueryable<T2> query2, string prop = null, string descend = null)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(prop))
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in properties)
                {
                    if (prop == item.Key)
                    {
                        prop = item.Value;
                    }
                }
                T2 subprop = query2.FirstOrDefault();

                if (prop.Contains("."))
                {
                    switch (prop.Split('.'))
                    {
                        default:
                            PropertyInfo property = subprop.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Split('.')[1]);
                            ParameterInfo[] index = property.GetIndexParameters();
                            object value = subprop.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Split('.')[1]).GetValue(subprop, index);

                            //This is the main issue, I have pretty much everything I should need, but I can't imagine how to write this OrderBy string properly.
                            //If I were to do it without the library: table.OrderBy(t => t.table2.Select(t2 => t2.field).FirstOrDefault());
                            //Without ordering by an ICollection property, like in the else below, string should look like: "field".
                            //Or in case of a 1 to 1 relationship, "table2.field".
                            query = DynamicQueryable.OrderBy(query, prop + (descend == "dec" ? " descending" : ""), value);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    query = DynamicQueryable.OrderBy(query, prop + (descend == "dec" ? " descending" : ""));
                }
            }

            return query;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11001172/2557128

Comment: It would if I were willing to decompile the library, make this change and then lose it as soon as an library update came up. But thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: Based on this article you can extend the library: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/marcinon/2010/01/14/building-custom-linq-expressions-made-easy-with-dynamicqueryable/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the `t => t.table2.Select(t2 => t2.field).FirstOrDefault()` with a supported function, `Min()`:

```
OrderBy("table2.Min(field)");
```

Comment: It worked. I still can't believe it. Been stuck on this for like, 3 weeks now. Thank you.

Comment: Also, thanks to this, I won't even need this overloaded version of the method anymore, with 2 generic types. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked. It is too bad `DynamicQuery` isn't an active project.